# Adding activation.jar & mail.jar to Android App

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

---

Hi,
I am trying to create a mailing application in Android using the Java APIs. I added activation.jar & mail.jar to my Android app. But I get an error : Could not find class 'javax.mail.internetMimebodyPart$MimePartDataHandl er', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler.

I added the jar files using the 'Add Jars' option available in Eclipse.

Please help me.

Comment: hi Sathigesan, did you got solution for this problem, Plz post the solution here. bcz i am also getting same error :(

Answer (score 1):

Android is not a full Java environment - it lack a lot of classes that are present in JRE.

For this reason you can not just take a jar targeting JRE and use it on Android: it will complain that classes are missing, like in your case.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Peter Knego !!! This is my issue for which I had to opt for the Java APIs. I have to create an Android mailing application which should display a html content on a mail when sent. But not as an attachment. Whatever html content I add, are getting removed by the default mail client of the phone. Could you please help me on it ?

Comment: hi Peter, u told that there is an issue in Android in above answer but you didn't told the solution plz post the solution here as i am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is another jar: additionnal.jar
Please add that too.
Hope it may solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Mathew, Thanks for your suggestion. But I could not find out that jar. If you have a link the site from where I can download, could you please post it here ?

Comment: You may use this link for your task. It also contains a link for downloading jar files. http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android